# CUDA out of memory when running validation test for SciBERT

Tags: python, pytorch, google-colaboratory, bert-language-model

I am trying to train SciBERT with a not-too-big dataset (roughly 10000 rows). I have partitioned the dataset as train, validation and loss, with proportion of 0.6, 0.2 and 0.2 respectively. Then I tried to train the model, with code like this:

```
from torch.optim import AdamW
from tqdm import tqdm
from statistics import mean

optim = AdamW(model.parameters(), lr=2e-5, eps=1e-8)

for epoch in range(4):
    epoch_losses = []
    validation_loss = []
    for x, y in tqdm(load_data(x_train, y_train, batch_size=10)):
        model.zero_grad()
        out = model(x, attention_mask=apply_attention_mask(x), labels=y)
        epoch_losses.append(out.loss.item())
        out.loss.backward()
        optim.step()
    print(f"epoch {epoch + 1} loss: {mean(epoch_losses)}")

    for x, y in load_data(x_validation, y_validation, batch_size=10):
    # validation data
        validation_output = model(x, attention_mask=apply_attention_mask(x), labels=y)
        validation_loss.append(validation_output.loss.item())
    print(f"Validation for epoch {epoch + 1} loss: {mean(validation_loss)}")
```

However, when I trained the model, after finishing with the training set and loading the validation set, Colab returned this error:

```
OutOfMemoryError: CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate 120.00 MiB (GPU 0; 14.75 GiB total capacity; 13.84 GiB already allocated; 24.81 MiB free; 14.59 GiB reserved in total by PyTorch) If reserved memory is >> allocated memory try setting max_split_size_mb to avoid fragmentation.  See documentation for Memory Management and PYTORCH_CUDA_ALLOC_CONF
```

From my understanding, when I tried to validate the model Colab just load SciBERT again to GPU, which led to this error; however, I am not sure about how to fix this problem:
[image]

So, what should I do to fix this error and get the validation loss for each epoch?

Answer (score 0):

Reduce the batch size and use gradient accumulation